# Generic Base Class with Constructor

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic class that looks like this:

```
public class DataServiceBase<T> : Screen where  T : EntityManager, new (){

    private T _entityManager;

    public T EntityManager {
        get {
            if (_entityManager == null)
            {
                _entityManager = new T();
            }
            return _entityManager;
        }
    }
```

Basically all I am trying to do is create an EntityManager of if it doesn't exist.  This actually works fine.  However, I need to modify this as T no longer has a parameterizerless constructor.  And so I can't use this methodology at all.

But I do need the EntityManager strongly typed at the derived level of the DataService as different entity managers handled different entities.

I am not sure how to resolve this.  One alternative I have tried is:

```
public DataServiceBase(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this._entityManager = entityManager;

    }
```

In other words, I pass it into the constructor, but now I no longer have the property strong typed.

Greg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just make the constructor argument take the generic type also

```
public DataServiceBase(T entityManager) {
    this._entityManager = entityManager;

}
```